# how can you make buttons open pages dynamically on the same layout?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development. I have been trying to link buttons to pages in a way that, when a button is clicked, it opens a page on the right side of the same layout, the same for different buttons on the layout. Am illustration is attached below where when Button 1 is clicked it opens Page 1, I want it to open Page 2 replacing Page 1 when Button 2 is clicked and the same for Button 3, 4 and 5. Can anybody tell me exactly what I need to do or include? Thank you.

[image: Sample image of what is supposed to be done]

Comment: Take a look at Master/Detail Flow

Answer (score 2):

**Create an Activity**, like `MainActivity.java`

**Create five fragments :**
like: `FragmentPageOne.java` , `FragmentPageTwo.java`, `FragmentPageThree.java`, `FragmentPageFour.java`, `FragmentPagefive.java`

**In your activity_main.xml :**
Create Two `LinearLayouts` inside one Parent `LinearLayout` and include one Linear Layout with five `buttons` and one `FrameLayout` which will be container on `MainActivity.java`.

**In your MainActivity.xml :**
Set `onClickListner` on every `buttons` , when you tab on first button it will show your first fragment on `FrameLayout` container, like that tab on buttons it will show you your fragment layouts on right side of the linear layout.

**Also look into this**

http://www.truiton.com/2017/01/android-bottom-navigation-bar-example/

https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/

**Your activity.xml looks like this :**

```
<LinearLayout
orientation = horizontal />

<LinearLayout>

//Five Buttons here

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
        app:elevation="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame_home">
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

 
</LinearLayout>
```

**Sample Code below :**

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()== R.id.home_ll){
            homeImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_home_active);
            searchImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_search);
            
          
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment().newInstance();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame_home, homeFragment)
                    .commit();


        }
        if(v.getId()== R.id.search_ll){
            homeImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_home);
            searchImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_search_active);
            
            SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment().newInstance();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame_home, searchFragment)
                    .commit();

 
        }
        if(v.getId()== R.id.categories_ll){
            homeImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_home);
            searchImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_search);
            
            CategoriesFragment categoriesFragment = new CategoriesFragment().newInstance();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame_home, categoriesFragment)
                    .commit();


        }
        if(v.getId()== R.id.cart_ll){
            homeImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_home);
            searchImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_search);
            
            CartFragment cartFragment = new CartFragment().newInstance();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame_home, cartFragment)
                    .commit();

 
        }
        if(v.getId()== R.id.account_ll){
            homeImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_home);
            searchImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_search);
          
  AccountFragment accountFragment = new AccountFragment().newInstance();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame_home, accountFragment)
                    .commit();
        
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this..On the click of `button` use can use `fragments`. For every button call `fragments` and handle `fragments` with add and replace.

Answer (score 0):

Define `fragments` for each pages. Take a dummy layout where you want to show your page. Replace it on `button` click with respective page `fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fragment` instead of layout page1, then you replace layout `fragment` when click `button1` or 2, ...
guide link: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

Just like the navigation drawer works. You can use the Fragments and then according to the button click, change the fragment! 
Let me know if it worked ! :)